# Why does property decorator show "object has no attribute"?

Tags: python, pyqt4, python-decorators

I have the following code:

```
import sys
import platform
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import QWebPage

class Render(QWebPage):
    def __init__(self):
        self.app = QApplication([])
        QWebPage.__init__(self)

    @property
    def html(self):
        return self.mainFrame().toHtml.toAscii()

page = Render()
print sys.version, platform.platform()
print 'html attribute?', [p for p in dir(page) if 'html' in p]
print page.html
```

gives this exception output:

```
stav@maia:$ python property.py
2.7.3 (default, Aug  1 2012, 05:14:39)
[GCC 4.6.3] Linux-3.2.0-38-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-12.04-precise
html attribute? ['html']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "property.py", line 18, in <module>
    print page.html
AttributeError: 'Render' object has no attribute 'html'
```

If I remove the `@property` decorator or I remove the `.toAscii` call, then it works.  But why does the error say there is no attribute even tho `dir(page)` shows it?

Comment: *Aside*: You probably meant `.toHtml().toAscii()`. Note the missing parentheses.

Comment: Property is only available to Python objects that descend from `object`

Comment: You're right @Robᵩ! ...you should submit that as an answer, that's it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The issue here is that Python gave a *misleading* error message.  The error message one would expect in this case is this:

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'toAscii'
```

But instead, Python gave a misleading error message:

```
AttributeError: 'Render' object has no attribute 'html'
```

That is, an `AttributeError` generated *within* the property function was presented as if it were an `AttributeError` for the property itself.

This strange behavior occurs when the class with your `@property` is derived from `QObject`.  It is a known issue in PyQt. In fact, the PyQt maintainers claim it is expected behavior (wrongly, IMHO).  See [this thread](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/pipermail/pyqt/2011-April/029667.html) for details.  (In that thread, it is claimed that `QObject` behaves identically to Python's built-in `object` class, but my own testing indicates otherwise.)

Comment: Super! I was hoping to get this answer originally, but Rob helped me get by the other issues I was having with calling ().

Comment: Unfortunately, I can only upvote this once. I spent several hours trying to figure out why 2 properties using the same QObject suddenly stopped working at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

You probably meant `.toHtml().toAscii()`. Note the missing parentheses.

Comment: I un-accepted this answer (can we do that?) since superbatfish actually answered the underlying question.  Thanks Rob.

Comment: Excellent. I'm pleased that superbatfish provided a high-quality answer.